# How to align a line between the gap of a gridpane?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to know how can I align a line between the gap of of the VGap/ HGap of the gridpane.

```
Public class Main extends Application {

    private StackPane root = new StackPane();
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Button("0 1"), new Button("0 2"), new Button("0 3"));
        gridPane.addRow(2, new Button("1 1"), new Button("1 2"), new Button("1 3"));
        gridPane.addRow(3, new Button("2 1"), new Button("2 2"), new Button("2 3"));
        gridPane.setHgap(20);
        gridPane.setVgap(20);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(gridPane);

        Separator separator = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        gridPane.add(separator, 0, 1, 1, GridPane.REMAINING);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Right now I have a grid pane and have the lines dangling along with prefixed X and Y values which will obviously be useless when the window is resized. 
Is there a way I can bind a line to be centered exactly between the H and V Gap?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post your code and show an image of what you have and what you are trying to achieve. You probably just need to have that line in the GrindPane cells between nodes if I had to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you learn to use FXML and SceneBuilder. In code, you need to use ColumnConstraints and RowConstraints to achieve what you need.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private StackPane root = new StackPane();
    private Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.add(new Button("0 0"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Button("2 0"), 2, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Button("4 0"), 4, 0);

        gridPane.add(new Button("0 2"), 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(new Button("2 2"), 2, 2);
        gridPane.add(new Button("4 2"), 4, 2);

        gridPane.add(new Button("0 4"), 0, 4);
        gridPane.add(new Button("2 4"), 2, 4);
        gridPane.add(new Button("4 4"), 4, 4);

        Separator hSeparatorOne = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        gridPane.add(hSeparatorOne, 0, 1, 5, 1);
        hSeparatorOne.setPrefHeight(10);
        hSeparatorOne.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        //hSeparatorOne.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        Separator hSeparatorTwo = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        gridPane.add(hSeparatorTwo, 0, 3, 5, 1);
        hSeparatorTwo.setPrefHeight(10);
        hSeparatorTwo.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        //hSeparatorTwo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        Separator vSeparatorOne = new Separator(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        gridPane.add(vSeparatorOne, 1, 0, 1, 5);
        vSeparatorOne.setPrefWidth(10);
        vSeparatorOne.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        //vSeparatorOne.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        Separator vSeparatorTwo = new Separator(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        gridPane.add(vSeparatorTwo, 3, 0, 1, 5);
        vSeparatorTwo.setPrefWidth(10);
        vSeparatorTwo.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        //vSeparatorTwo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        ColumnConstraints columnConstraintsColumnZero = new ColumnConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, HPos.CENTER, true);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraintsSeperatorOne = new ColumnConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, HPos.CENTER, true);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraintsColumnTwo = new ColumnConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, HPos.CENTER, true);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraintsSeperatorThree = new ColumnConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, HPos.CENTER, true);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraintsColumnFour = new ColumnConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, HPos.CENTER, true);
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnConstraintsColumnZero, columnConstraintsSeperatorOne, columnConstraintsColumnTwo, columnConstraintsSeperatorThree, columnConstraintsColumnFour);

        RowConstraints rowConstraintsRowZero = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, VPos.CENTER, true);
        RowConstraints rowConstraintsSeperatorOne = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, VPos.CENTER, true);
        RowConstraints rowConstraintsRowTwo = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, VPos.CENTER, true);
        RowConstraints rowConstraintsSeperatorThree = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, VPos.CENTER, true);
        RowConstraints rowConstraintsRowFour = new RowConstraints(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Priority.SOMETIMES, VPos.CENTER, true);
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowConstraintsRowZero, rowConstraintsSeperatorOne, rowConstraintsRowTwo, rowConstraintsSeperatorThree, rowConstraintsRowFour);

        gridPane.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        root.getChildren().add(gridPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Do you know how can I set the stroke length of those lines? I tried setting the style `hSeparatorOne.setStyle("-fx-stroke-width: 30;");` and changing the pref height of it changes the spacing between the rows. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I tried that solution but it changes the colour of only one part of the rows and columns. Here is how it looks like https://imgur.com/TIV2dq8 
I just want it to take all the area between the lines and colour that part.

Comment: I am on vacation. I will look at it later.

Comment: Hello @user3845934. If this answer solved your original problem, accept it and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true) you will have to add nodes for the lines in a row or column between the "real" items.

E.g. for a horizontal line you might do something like this:

```
Separator separator = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
gridPane.add(separator, col, row, 1, GridPane.REMAINING);
```

Here is a complete solution with resizable borders:

```
package example.grid;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Region makeVerticalLine() {
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        vb.setPrefHeight(1);
        vb.setPrefWidth(1);
        vb.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        return vb;
    }

    private Region makeHorizontalLine() {
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        hb.setPrefHeight(1);
        hb.setPrefWidth(1);
        hb.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        return hb;
    }

    private void bindWidths(DoubleProperty width, Region ... regions) {
        for (Region r : regions) {
            r.prefWidthProperty().bind(width);
        }
    }

    private void bindHeights(DoubleProperty height, Region ... regions) {
        for (Region r : regions) {
            r.prefHeightProperty().bind(height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane parent = new BorderPane();
        Slider slider = new Slider(1, 100, 3);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        Region h11 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h21 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h31 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h13 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h23 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h33 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h15 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h25 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region h35 = makeHorizontalLine();
        Region v1 = makeVerticalLine();
        Region v2 = makeVerticalLine();

        ColumnConstraints numCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        numCol.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
        numCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        ColumnConstraints sepCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        sepCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        RowConstraints numRow = new RowConstraints();
        numRow.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
        numRow.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        RowConstraints sepRow = new RowConstraints();
        sepRow.setVgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        GridPane.setRowSpan(v1, GridPane.REMAINING);
        GridPane.setRowSpan(v2, GridPane.REMAINING);

        grid.addRow(0, new Label("7"), v1, new Label("8"), v2, new Label("9"));
        grid.add(h11,0,1);
        grid.add(h21,2,1);
        grid.add(h31,4,1);
        grid.add(new Label("4"), 0, 2);
        grid.add(new Label("5"), 2, 2);
        grid.add(new Label("6"), 4, 2);
        grid.add(h13,0,3);
        grid.add(h23,2,3);
        grid.add(h33,4,3);
        grid.add(new Label("1"), 0, 4);
        grid.add(new Label("2"), 2, 4);
        grid.add(new Label("3"), 4, 4);
        grid.add(h15,0,5);
        grid.add(h25,2,5);
        grid.add(h35,4,5);
        grid.add(new Label("0"), 2, 6);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(numCol,sepCol,numCol,sepCol,numCol);
        grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(numRow,sepRow,numRow,sepRow,numRow,sepRow,numRow);

        bindHeights(slider.valueProperty(), h11,h13,h15,h21,h23,h25,h31,h33,h35);
        bindWidths(slider.valueProperty(), v1, v2);

        VBox controls = new VBox(slider);
        parent.setTop(controls);
        parent.setCenter(grid);

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: And note that [`GridPane#gridLinesVisible`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#gridLinesVisibleProperty()) is meant for debugging only.

Comment: @swpalmer I tried implementing your solution but I'm having trouble with how to implement it in my code. I tried this https://pastebin.com/NZcAmMf5 but it does not work.