Is there a way to seperate the formatting of an object (spacing, padding, etc.) from others within a grid pane in javafx
So i'm recreating the structure of a calculator on javafx. Not for the functionality, but only for the looks. I have created the buttons and set the gaps between them to be 16, horizontally and vertically. However, when I had a text field object to display the numbers/results (again not for functionality, but for display), the buttons are affected by the size of the text field object. Therefore, the first row where I placed the text field object has a huge gap.
This is the code I have for that section:
        // layout manager: organize window contents
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        
        // Scene: contains window content
        // parameters: layout manager; width window; height window
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        // attach/display Scene on Stage (window)
        mainStage.setScene( mainScene );
        
        // create TextField
        TextField nameField = new TextField("");
        root.add(nameField, 3, 1);
        
        root.setStyle( "-fx-font-size: 24;" );
        
        // to add space between rows and columns
        root.setHgap( 16 ); // between horizontal objects
        root.setVgap( 16 ); // between vertical objects
        
        // create all buttons
        Button button0 = new Button("0");
        Button button1 = new Button("1");
        Button button2 = new Button("2");
        Button button3 = new Button("3");
        Button button4 = new Button("4");
        ...
        
        // parameters: object, column # (X), row # (Y)
        // first row
        root.add(buttonAllClear, 3, 2);
        root.add(buttonClear, 4, 2);
        root.add(buttonDelete, 5, 2);
        root.add(buttonDivides, 6, 2);
    
        // second row
        root.add(button7, 3, 3);
        root.add(button8, 4, 3);
        root.add(button9, 5, 3);
        root.add(buttonTimes, 6, 3);
        // 
    //when I run the code i get:
    //[    text field       ]
    //ac                    c    del    /
    //7                     8    9     *
    //4                     5    6     -
    //1                     2    3     +
    //0                     .    =

//but i want: 
//[    text field       ]
//ac     c     del   /
//7      8     9     *
//4      5     6     -
//1      2     3     +
//0      .     =
    


Have a look at the methods of GridPane.  Notice there are actually two add methods.  You may want to consider using the other one.  If you’re not sure how it works, click on the method name to read the full details of what it does.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727942/how-to-align-a-line-between-the-gap-of-a-gridpane/57730140#57730140

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50184603/javafx-button-sizing-hbox-and-vbox-dont-align-properly-and-gaps-visible/50190398#50190398

Spanning multiple columns with a TextField
You can set the columnSpan on a node in GridPane to have it span a defined number of columns.
GridPane.setColumnSpan(
        textField,
        4
);

The span can also be configured while adding a node (as pointed at by Trashgod in comments).
gridPane.add(textField, 0, 0, 4, 1);  

Separating the layout into different panes
Alternately, you could not place the text field for the calculator in the grid, instead have a VBox containing the textfield and gridPane.  Then only use the GridPane for the buttons.
Example
This example demonstrates both approaches, using columnSpan for the equals button and placing the text field in a separate row in a VBox.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CalcApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String[][] buttonText = {
                {"ac", "c", "del", "/"},
                { "7", "8", "9",   "*"},
                { "4", "5", "6",   "-"},
                { "1", "2", "3",   "+"},
                { "1", "2", "="}
        };

        GridPane buttonGrid = new GridPane(5, 5);

        for (int r = 0; r < buttonText.length; r++) {
            String[] rowText = buttonText[r];
            Button[] buttonsInRow =
                    Arrays.stream(rowText)
                            .map(CalcApp::createButton)
                            .toArray(Button[]::new);

            buttonGrid.addRow(r, buttonsInRow);
        }

        buttonGrid.getChildren().stream()
                .filter(CalcApp::isEqualsButton)
                .forEach(equalsButton ->
                        GridPane.setColumnSpan(
                                equalsButton,
                                2
                        )
                );

        int nCols = buttonText[0].length;
        for (int c = 0; c < nCols; c++) {
            ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
            columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100.0 / nCols);
            buttonGrid.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        }

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px;");
        textField.setMinHeight(TextField.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, textField, buttonGrid);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        VBox.setVgrow(buttonGrid, Priority.SOMETIMES);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static boolean isEqualsButton(Node n) {
        return n instanceof Button b && "=".equals(b.getText());
    }

    private static Button createButton(String text) {
        Button button = new Button(text);
        button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button.setMinSize(Button.USE_PREF_SIZE, Button.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        GridPane.setVgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setHgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
        button.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px;");

        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

Alternative: using a TilePane
A similar solution that uses a TilePane rather than GridPane, but keeps the TextField out of the TilePane which contains the buttons.
Related
An explanation for some of the constraints used here to create the button grid pane is provided in the answer to a similar question:

Resizing buttons inside a grid pane.


Thank you so much! This is all new to me (javafx) and there're so many methods to look at, so it got a bit overwhelming. I appreciate the help :)
